# sub-Views on a ScrollView for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, subview

I'm building an iPhone application using Monotouch.

It uses three views, side by side, the purpose is to switch between views by scrolling from right to left and left to right.. I don't know it's the right way to do this, for now I have a ScrollView where I add three sub-Views. I then confronts to three problems.

1/ I would like to create my sub-views on the storyboard with InterfaceBuilder and being able to add each views programmatically, but I don't know how to do that.

2/ I don't know how "delegate" at the sub-ViewController of the current sub-View.

3/ I'm afraid about the performance and the memory consumption, since the subviews are (I guess) always loaded, even when inactive.

anyone know the good way to do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a choice, i would create 3 views and using UIAnimation will show the scroll effect. But for ur scrollview questions:

1.if u want to create view in Interface builder, u can use IBOutlet and show the view or directly add the views to scrollview. there is no need for adding the view programatically.

3.since ur using Interface builder, views will be created only once, so u can scroll any number of time only 3 views will be there. so no need to worry about the memory.

i didn understand ur 2nd point. please be more specific.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. My second question was how to insert a SubViewController in ScrollViewController but the answer to the first question answers.